# Смена изображения при клике и скрытие первой картинки

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть блок внутри которого есть два изображения, которые должны меняться при клике и кликнув первая картинка должна пропадать, а вторая появляться, но вторая должна быть чуть ниже чем первая

Не могу понять как скрыть первую картинку и чтобы при повторном нажатии после появляения второй картинки дальше ничего не менялось, т.е. идет первый клик - изображение сменилось на второе, затем клик на второе ничего не менял

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img_container").click(function() {
    $("#img_container img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
  });
});
```

```css
#img_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#img_container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 300px;
}

#img_container img.transparent {
  opacity: 0;
}

#link_onclick {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.transparent {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img_container">
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/09/11/1457d4ffba1aded.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/explosion-colored-powder-white-background_1112-1555.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: А оно второй раз и не должно меняться т.к ты задал класс .top именно второй картинке и у нее меняешь класс transparent. Как я понял, тебе нужно, чтобы при нажатии на блок, картиника, котороая видна, пропадала, а вторая - появлялась, так?

Comment: @ДанилСкрипник при загрузке должна появляться одна картиника, которая сейчас находится за второй, затем на клик появляется вторая и пропадает первая и вторая должна быть чуть ниже, класс задал чтобы застилить вторую картинку

Answer (score 0):

Добавил класс .bottom
В JS комменты

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(this).find('img.top').hide(); // верхняя изначально скрыта

  $("#img_container").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img.bottom').addClass('transparent'); // при клике скрываем нижнюю

    $(this).find('img.top').show().removeClass('transparent'); // при клике показываем верхнюю
  });
});
```

```css
#img_container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#img_container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 300px;
}

#img_container img.transparent {
  opacity: 0;
}

#link_onclick {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.top {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.transparent {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img_container">
  <img class="bottom" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_origin_min_pic/16/09/11/1457d4ffba1aded.jpg" />
  <img class="top" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/explosion-colored-powder-white-background_1112-1555.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии мало только менять класс `transparent`еще и нужно переключать между картинками класс `top`. Так можно будет циклически переключать картинки

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#img_container").click(function() {
    $("#img_container > img").toggleClass("transparent");
    $("#img_container > img").toggleClass("top");
  });
});

<div id="img_container">
  <img class="transparent" src="..." />
  <img class="top" src="..." />
</div>
```

Comment: Кста, можно написать тупо в одно действие `$("#img_container > img").toggleClass("transparent, top");`

Comment: Да, точняк. Не знал, что так можно)